# ShareKit in Xcode 4 - lots of deprecated

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, sharekit

I have just loaded the ShareKit files into my project (which worked nicely otherwise), and went to build and run (with no code additions as yet).

I received 11 warnings and 37 errors!

[image: Screen grab from xcode]

Is there something I'm missing here? The warnings are for deprecated functions in the SHK**** files.

Any ideas?

Using Xcode 4.

Thanks for any assistance,
Kolya

Comment: You can copy paste the text with the error, but yeah known issue. You can fix the deprecates and errors manually or drop some files from the project.

Comment: Thanks Jano. Unfortunately, the files with the errors are the ones I need. I guess I'll work through removing/fixing the deprecated code. Has no one done this already?!

Comment: You could see the current ShareKit forks at github, i'm pretty sure someone already did that for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This fork (https://github.com/mogeneration/ShareKit) compiles/works perfectly on XCode 4/iPhone 3.2.1 Simulator, it should be good for you, besides is based on the latest oficial version :)

Comment: Thanks Diego - all functioning well.

Answer (score 0):

Try [reborn ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/) - supported by a community.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [reborn ShareKit](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/), but still get some warnings after adding the shareKit folder to my project. For some reason, when compiling the example project, there are no warnings at all. :(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has been having problems with ShareKit with iOS5, Facebook released their own wrapper which is way more compatible because you know, Facebook did it.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk