# iOS >> ShareKit >> Warnings: Is There a Way to Get Rid of the Warnings / Will Apple Review Reject the Project

Tags: ios, warnings, appstore-approval, sharekit

I'm implementing **ShareKit** in my app. Everything is working fine, but there are many warnings caused by the ShareKit files.

When I look into them it seems that they all relate to just a few issues:

- ShareKit is using some **deprecated** items (mostly "font" related).
- **FBLOG2** - many times ShareKit calling this feature, but don't use it; so the warning is always: Expresion result unused
- In FBRequest.m file there is a method called "(id)parseXMLResponse:(NSData*)data error:(NSError**)error". the warning I get is "**Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'id' from incompatible type 'FBXMLHandler *'**"

Can anyone direct me to how to solve these warnings?

OR... Does anyone know if Apple App Review rejects applications that carry these warnings (as I said, besides the fact that the warnings are being called, my app is working fine and all the ShareKit features I had implemented are functioning fine as well)?

Comment: Checkout this post.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933330/sharekit-in-xcode-4-lots-of-deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharekit hasn't been updated by the authors in over a year. That being said, some things have changed since then (APIs updated, method deprecated, etc.) However, Sharekit should still work. If the warnings bother you (as they should), they shouldn't be very difficult to fix. If you need help, google the specific warnings.

For example, the font issue is just `setFont` has been deprecated in favor of `cell.textLabel.font = ...`